# How to find Binary file in solaris?

Tags: solaris

I am working on Sun Netra T5220, and working on project Session border controller(SBC). In one of the step I had to follow this procedure "copy the binary to a folder and run OPenSBC".
Can any body help me which binary file, I need to put on the folder and the way how to find the binary file?

Answer (score 2):

Solaris should come equipped with the good old `find` command, one of my favorite tools. You can use it to find a file like so:

```
find / -type f -name "OPenSBC"
```

If you are unsure on the case:

```
find / -type f -iname "opensbc"
```

If you have a good idea of where the file is, you can use a different loation as your starting point:

```
find /etc -type f -iname "opensbc"
```

to provide you with a better answer we'll need more details on this "binary file". We only know as much as you've told us :)

Comment: Note that the -iname option is Gnu specific so not supported by Solaris 10 bundled find.

Comment: @jilliagre I completely forgot. Thanks! You can obtain GNU find for solaris here if you wish: http://www.sunfreeware.com/

Answer (score 1):

"and run OPenSBC" ? see if there's a file called "OPenSBC" and then go to the directory where its stored and do `./OpenSBC`. Otherwise if still not sure, you can use `file` command. `file <filename>` and see the output for words like `executable` etc.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers given: if you need functionality provided by the GNU variants of these tools, most Solaris installations these days have OpenCSW packages installed in `/opt/csw`.

John T's answer with the `-iname` flag is completely valid if you use `/opt/csw/bin/gfind` (note the extra `g`) instead of `find` -- with one caveat: the version of `gfind` installed on our Solaris machines (and probably on yours) has an issue with NFS mounted filesystems hosted by Linux.

It seems when that build of `gfind` was made they didn't add support for large filesystems (read [this documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html) for `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE`, `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE`, `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` if you're curious).  As a consequence, it just silently fails to recurse into any directory mapped from a Linux file server.